# Recover cached website data

Tags: data-recovery

I went to settings then sites and downloads then manage website data and deleted cached info. Can I restore that info? in Samsung Internet browser on a Samsung tablet?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **No**.

The web browser cache is part of the app-internal data of the Webbrowser app. Unless you made a backup the deleted data is gone.

Data recovery on Android is very complicated as you first require root permissions and then need a tool that is able to parse the used file-system of your device and find deleted files. I case of some deleted JPEG images there is a small chance to find them back, however a webbrowser cache comprises of several apps and is most likely saved to dozens of fragments in the flash memory which makes a recovery very unlikely.